# What does __src__ in IE mean?

Tags: html

I happened to come across a google code for IE .

```
<IMG style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 616px; HEIGHT: 616px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: -154px" src="https://cbks0.googleapis.com/cbk?output=tile&amp;cb_client=apiv3&amp;v=4&amp;zoom=2&amp;x=2&amp;y=0&amp;panoid=AmKl8CauDW9s1OBl6hpC3Q&amp;fover=2&amp;onerr=3" __src__="https://cbks0.googleapis.com/cbk?output=tile&amp;cb_client=apiv3&amp;v=4&amp;zoom=2&amp;x=2&amp;y=0&amp;panoid=AmKl8CauDW9s1OBl6hpC3Q&amp;fover=2&amp;onerr=3" __gm_ticket__="1" gm_id="null" mb="false">
```

It contains tags unknown to me like `__src__`, `gm_id`, `__gm_ticket__` ..
Anyone knows whar they are ?

Comment: src is "source". In here, it is the source of the picture (img). _ _src_ _ looks like a parameter that is used in JavaScript to save some datas. Where did you find that code?

Comment: What? With a pair of underscores before and after the word?

Comment: for _ _ src _ _ it looks crasy but for __gm_ticket__="1" gm_id="null" mb="false", parameters contains datas. Instread of saving them in DB, they put them in custom parameters in the <img> ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The double underscore is a naming convention which means the values of `src` or `gm_ticket` should not be edited by the user. This is more efficient than wrapping each global function in a closure. Closures can be `very memory hungry since every instance needs its own function to encapsulate the local vars`.

**References**

- [Trying to be Private in JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/trying-to-be-private-in-javascript)
- [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/basics)